# are there any questions that can be asked without a helping verb

Tags: grammar

I'm writing to ask can we ask about this sentence( he was rich) with out using any helping verbs?? And which one of these sentences is correct (how does he love you OR how he loves you)

Comment: Yes. For example, "Was he rich?" Although you may think of *was* as a helping verb, it is not a helping verb in that particular sentence; rather, it is the only verb.

Comment: Thank you i wondered if you could possibly answer my next question too!

Comment: Well, yes, but it **is** an auxiliary verb, for the predicate adjective _rich_. Predicate adjectives and predicate nouns take _be_ as an auxiliary verb, just like the Passive and the Progressive constructions do. I.e, _be_ is always an auxiliary (notice that it performs Subject-Auxiliary Inversion in _Was he rich_ (rather than **Did he be rich?*).

Comment: "How does he love you?" is an acceptable question, although strangely worded. "How he loves you" is an incomplete sentence. This website might better help you understand: http://ell.stackexchange.com/

Comment: "Cream in your coffee?" That's a question without any verbs at all, helping or otherwise.

Comment: I know it's incomplete but is it ok to use it in friendly conversations???

Comment: When I say it's incomplete, I mean it doesn't make sense. The only time it would be used in conversation (that I can think of) is this: if a gentleman gives someone a gift that shows his affection, you might exclaim to the recipient, "Oh, how he loves you!"

Comment: This may be a matter of clashing terminology, but usually an auxiliary verb is an adjunct to the main verb of clause.  The former determines tense and aspect;the latter carries the main sense.

Comment: How do I love thee? (Sonnet 43). How he loves you! Would that be incomplete?

Comment: Why? How? When and where? Who? -- Me!?  What about your family? How to know?  How so? Etc.

Comment: Let's just say that, without context or punctuation, "how he loves you" is complete and utter nonsense.

Answer (score 2):

**Question 1** - For sentences with an auxiliary (a.k.a. helping verb)

In casual speech or writing, as long as you have rising intonation or a question mark, any of these sentences can be made into a question. Usually, context is enough to let the other participant(s) know what you are asking.

> **Person 1:** He used to have a Ferrari.
>
> **Person 2:** He was rich?
>
> **Person 1:** Yes, he used to be very wealthy before the recession.

In more formal speech or writing, I would recommend avoiding this sort of question formation, because it deviates from the more "standard" form of question formation with auxiliaries- [subject-auxiliary inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93auxiliary_inversion). So if you are constraining yourself to this standard, you cannot form your question without an auxiliary verb.

**Question 2** - [Do-insertion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do-support) (also known as do-support)

Your second question is a little ambiguous. Are you wanting to know which one is correct as a declarative statement or as a question? If you want to know which one would be correct as a question, this has also been answered in a broader sense [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/37902/do-i-have-to-use-do-in-any-wh-question). The first answer by @StoneyB does a very good job of explaining when it is necessary to use insert "do" into a question. I will quote/paraphrase their answer here:

Do NOT use "do" when:

> - **a)** when the *Wh-* word is the **Subject** of the clause
>
>   > Who **told** you that?
>   >     Which bus **goes** downtown?
> - **b)** when the tensed verb is an auxiliary (be, have, modals)
>
>   > Who **are** you?
>   >     Why **have** you come here?
>   >     What **can** you do?

USE do when there is no auxiliary present (do becomes the auxiliary) like in:

> > **Q:** What did you say? → **A:** I said *X*.
> >     **Q:** Which shirt did you wear? → **A:** I wore *X*.
> >     **Q:** Who did you give it to? → **A:** I gave it *to X*.
> >     **Q:** Where did you go? → **A:** I went *to X*.
> >     **Q:** Why did you go? → **A:** I went *because X*.

Your question would look like this:

> > **Q:** How does he love you? → **A:** He loves you *by X*.

Comment: I'm Ron Burgundy?